# Running Java from a Script with Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I am trying to use Nashorn as a scripting language and I would like to start a Java program from that a script that is run with Nashorn.

I can sucsessfully run the following script with Nashorn:

```
#!/usr/bin/jjs -fv
$EXEC("ls -l")
```

However the following script seems to do nothing:

```
#!/usr/bin/jjs -fv
$EXEC("java -version")
```

On the commandline `java -version` of course works...

What might be my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Nashorn can call methods from Java classes. So you can just use it to evoke the `main`-method of the main class of the program you want to start. A precondition is that you run jjs with the the parameter `-cp path/to/java/classes/of/program` so it knows about the classes of said program.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However I am really looking for a solution to start another JVM from Nashorn ... actually my final goal would even be to start several new JVMs from one Nashorn script ...